# printing javascript equations via html

Tags: javascript, beginner, html

Here's a (probably) simple question for you all, I need some simple equations generated via javascript to display on my website, but I am unable to do so. Following online tutorials, I have:

```
<h2>The += Operator</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var w = 5;
var x = 5;
var y = 5;
var z = 5;
w += 5;
x += 6;
y += 7;
z += 8;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = wxyz;
</script>
```

Any suggestions? Thank you and have a good day :)

Comment: Code Review is for open-ended questions about code that already works correctly (to the best of your knowledge). Questions seeking help about debugging or understanding code are off-topic for Code Review, and may be on-topic for [SO]. See [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: im not sure what js equations are, i assume you mean either math expressions or js code, if the latter you should have a look at codemirror or ace text editor which is great for showing code with js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably post this on stackoverflow, since this is for code reviewing.

You have an error here

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = wxyz;
```

Do this to see what happens

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = w + " " + x + " " + y + " " + z;
```